# Linq query convert to List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml, type-conversion

I have this code

```
List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
    var query = from c in doc.Root.Elements("a").Elements("b")
        select new { ID = c.Element("val").Value};
```

How can I convert query to List without loop foreach ?

```
{ ID = c.Element("val")}
```

are strings of course

**EDIT**

my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>
    <b>
      <val>other data</val>
    </b>
    <b>

      <val>other data</val>
    </b>
  </a>
</aBase>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
IDs = query.Select(a  => a.ID).ToList();
```

or if you'd like to do it in one line

```
List<string> IDs = (from c in doc.Root.Elements("a").Elements("b")
        select c.Element("val").Value).ToList()
```

Comment: It throws me [System.NullReferenceException]. Why?

Comment: @Saint_pl I just used the xml you provided and don't see that exception. But my guess is that one of your b's don't have a val.

Comment: Ok, it works great. In real project I have other names, and I made typo (no intellisense ;) ) Thanx

Answer (score 4):

The anonymous type isn't really helping you since you only need a sequence of *strings*, not any sort of tuple. Try:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
var query = from c in doc.Root.Elements("a").Elements("b")
            select c.Element("val").Value;

var IDs = query.ToList();
```

Personally, I would just use method-syntax all the way:

```
var IDs = doc.Root.Elements("a")
                  .Elements("b")
                  .Select(c => c.Element("val").Value)
                  .ToList();
```